# What field type, tokenizer and query should I use in Solr to be able to search field storing JSON?

Tags: json, solr

I am working with a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (v1.4.1) index that has a field that is storing serialized JSON.  Here is an example of the JSON stored in a field called "json" on a document in [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

```
{
    "uri": "http://localhost/individual/n503",
    "name": "Smith, Richard",
    "title": "Programming CIO",
    "items": [{
        "uri": "http://localhost/individual/n1873",
        "type": "http://localhost/individual/book"
    }]
}
```

I would like to query this serialized JSON field for the existence of URI (like `http://localhost/individual/n1873`).  I'm using Scala with SolrJ (v1.4.1) to query the results.  The function looks like this:

```
def documentsForUri(uri: String) = {
  var query = new SolrQuery();
  query.setQuery( "json:" + uri )
  var rsp = solr.query( query )
  rsp.getResults()
}
```

By passing `uri = "http://localhost/individual/n1873"` to the function results 0 documents.  I tried changing the ":" to be "\:" and that didn't seem to help.  In my schema.xml, I have tried defining the field as a `solr.StrField` and `solr.TextField`.  For example:

```
<types>
...
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"/>
...
</types>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

The field definitions I tried looked like this:

```
<fields>
...
  <field name="json" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
...
</fields>
```

and this:

```
<fields>
...
  <field name="json" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
...
</fields>
```

Neither of these combinations worked with the escaped uri query string ("\:") and non-escaped uri string (":").

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I'm really trying to do the equivalent to a "like" in an SQL query on a field that has serialized JSON stored in it.

Comment: I did not use scala before, but you may change your argument from uri = "http://localhost/individual/n1873" to "uri": "http://localhost/individual/n503"

Comment: So you have no analyzers configured in your definitions of `text` and `text_ws`? Have you tried with the default (i.e. the sample schema) definitions of these field types?

Comment: @miette The hope was to be able to search on any URL references within the serialized json.  `http://localhost/individual/n503` didn't work either when I tried it.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I did try the lucene SimpleAnalyzer and the StandardAnalyzer.  These seem to tokenize the json and split the URIs apart.  For example, `http://localhost/individual/n503` would become tokenized like `http`, `localhost`, `individual` and `n`.  There might be a better Analyzer, but I was hoping to search on the full URL in the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a JSON tokenizer for Solr](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1690), unfortunately the patch was never committed so it's not included in Solr. Or you could just use [Noggit](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/labs/noggit/) (or whatever JSON parser you like) and preprocess JSON on the client (i.e. in your Scala code), then place this processed data in a separate, indexed field in Solr.

Comment: hey Mauricio Scheffer i am new to solr.. can you please help me to know how to include JSONKeyValueTokenizerFactory into solr